# how does the "@" location tag work?

Tags: frameworks, dictionary, reference, tags, location

for better understanding check out this link first: http://sxsw.usehipster.com/questions/where-are-the-best-breakfast-tacos-in-austin

as you can see there, some answers have a reference to a location which is show on the map on the right. A user can do that by adding the “@“ symbol before the location name.

I'd like to know how that works. Did the guys from usehipster.com developed that by themselve or is that maybe a framework I can use too?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks custom-made - i.e. not a framework. Shouldn't be too hard - just scan the entry for `@\w+`, plug that into Google Local Search (possibly specify the city), and plug the output into a Google Map. See e.g. this for an example of Google Local Search API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=localsearch#the_hello_world_of_local_search